# Executable with selenium and chromedriver in Python

Tags: selenium, performance, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I saw a topic about this subject here on the forum, but it didn't solve my problem. I made an executable (using auto-py-to-exe) from a code using Selenium with Chromedriver to run on other computers.

In my computer this executable works perfectly, but when I try on other computers, it doesn't work.
I've wasted a few days looking for answers on the internet, but so far without success.
If anyone has had this problem before and can help me, I would appreciate it.

The error is always the following:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
  File "subprocess.py", line 858, in _init_
  File "subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Automacao_Selenium4.0.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in _init_
  File "selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 89, in _init_
  File "selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home```
````